# Column to rows transfer

Tags: sql

```
**Column A**             **Column B**
MEMBERSHIP NO.         167337
MEMBER NAME            CHIRAGBHAI VASANI
FIRM NAME              MEHRA ANIL AND ASSOCIATES
COMAPANY ADDRESS       GANGANAGAR 
MOBILE NO.             9723989669
EMAIL ID               CHIRAG9355@GMAIL.COM
MEMBERSHIP NO.         530301
MEMBER NAME            MANMEETKAUR KHALSA
FIRM NAME              MANMEETKAUR@ASSOCIATES
COMAPANY ADDRESS       MALERKOTLA, PUNJAB
MOBILE NO.             9429050703
EMAIL ID               CA.MANMEET70@GMAIL.COM
```

I want This.

```
MEMBERSHIP NO.      MEMBER NAME           FIRM NAME                  COMAPANY ADDRESS       MOBILE NO.   EMAIL ID 
 167337             CHIRAGBHAI VASANI         MEHRA ANIL AND ASSOCIATES      GANGANAGAR         9723989669   CHIRAG9355@GMAIL.COM
 530301             MANMEETKAUR KHALSA        MANMEETKAUR@ASSOCIATES         MALERKOTLA, PUNJAB     9429050703   CA.MANMEET70@GMAIL.COM
```

Comment: This is a ‘please do my homework question’ which isn’t done on SE. Please edit to properly phrase your question, especially mentioning what you have tried to do yourself.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results imply an ordering of the rows.  However, without a column specifying the ordering, you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* rows.  If you have an ordering column, then you can assign a group and use conditional aggregation.

For instance, if each group begins with `'MEMBERSHIP NO.'`, then you could use:

```
select max(case when a = 'MEMBERSHIP NO.' then b end) as membership_no,
       max(case when a = 'MEMBER NAME' then b end) as member_name,
       . . .    -- and so on for the rest of the columns
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when a = 'MEMBERSHIP NO.' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```